# How to change string into a list of characters in C# for beginners?

Tags: c#, string, loops, type-conversion, boolean

I am currently trying to use Codecademy to learn how to use C# yet the last 'test' for the very second lesson asks us to convert a string to a list. I looked at a forum and it said you had to use loops which was not taught in the course yet, yet I wanted to use a loop anyway, how could I create the list with the for loop which possibly needs fixing? (And maybe help to check whether or not the other code is correct as it asks to convert bool to string and a random data type to another which I chose byte for.) Thanks.

```
  bool pick = true;
  byte number = 5;
  string myTest = "Ping Pong";
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(pick));
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(number));
  for ((char(myTest));)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
```

Comment: `foreach (char c in myTest) Console.WriteLine(c);`

Answer (score 3):

You use [`string.ToCharArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-5.0) to convert the string into an array of characters.

However you don't need to do that just to iterate over it, `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can iterate over it directly.

Also `for ((char(myTest));)` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: +1, but if you make an assertion like "`for ((char(myTest));)` makes absolutely no sense," you need to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

An string is already a character array and because System.String implements `IEnumerable<char>` you can just loop it:

```
/* 
  References you need:
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
*/

string myTest = "Ping Pong";

//looping a string
foreach (char character in myTest)
{
    Console.WriteLine(character);
}

//Explicit converting a string to list of chars
var listChars = new List<char>();
listChars = myTest.ToList();

foreach (char character  in listChars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(character);
}
```

Comment: By the way, you can only use foreach for members that implement IEnumerable. Foreach is nothing more than syntactic sugar to iterate over an enumerator. See more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=net-5.0